# Ruby gems loosing native extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have been noticing a trend, but not a cause, over the past few months. Every few weeks when I go into a RoR project (not always the same project) and start up the server I receive an error that usually contains the phrase `'require': incompatible library version`

To fix it, I usually have to do `gem pristine` along with the gem name that was within the error line; for instance:

```
gem pristine nokogiri
```

This fixes the extensions; but, when trying to run the server again, the same error pops up with a different gem. The only way to fix it would be to run the code above on all gems like so:

```
gem pristine --all
```

This takes a long time, but faster than doing one at a time and it fixes the issue every time.

This last time 25 different gems had to be restored.

**Question**

Here is my question. Is there a reason that any of you know for why this would be happening so often? Is there something that I am doing to cause these to become corrupted? Or maybe is there something that is happening on my machine the way it is setup to cause these extensions to continually get corrupted and have to be fixed? Any insight or thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Some possibilities: 1) You've updated Ruby without recompiling the gems? 2) OS updates running in the background updating system libraries?

Comment: Are you using a ruby version manager i.e. RVM or RBENV?  If not you may want to.

Comment: @Casper, could be #2. But, would either of those cause this error so frequently?

Comment: @lacostenycoder, I do run RVM

Comment: You would need to save the exact error message. It should report which library linkages have become disconnected. Save the error message each time, and then look for a common pattern. This should start to give you a clue where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Thank you, Casper. I am keeping track. It happened again. So, I am going to see if I can keep track as you suggested and find a pattern.